# Edit column browser of a playlist in iTunes 12.4

Tags: itunes

Whenever I create a new playlist a new design is showing up. The problem here is, I can't edit the column browser anymore i.e. create a new column or change its order or size.

Is there a way to solve this problem? If it's not possible, is there a way to go back to the previous design without downgrading iTunes?
I've heard that this new design was for the "Playlist" mode and back in 12.2 you were able to change this mode back to "Song" mode. Unfortunately, I wasn't able to find it. Is it gone, too?

Here's a picture of the old design:
[image: old design]

And here one of the new design:
[image: new design]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been able to find the tool where you're able to switch between these two modes. It used to be on the upper right, but now you can find it in **View As/Title** on the View menu.

Answer (score -1):

1. select your playlist
2. go to view>view as, then change from playlist to songs